# PHP appendChild analog in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

My aim is to insert an HMTL element only once in the foreach loop inside Smarty, but insert Children elements as many cycles as foreach loop has. With PHP the working code looks like this:

```
$counter1 = 0;
foreach ($secCont->getContent() as $row) {
if ($row->getType() == "head") {
    $counter1++;
    if ($counter1 == 1) {
        $theadNode = $html->createElement("thead");
        $tableNode->appendChild($theadNode);
    }
    $tr = $html->createElement("tr");
    $theadNode->appendChild($tr);
    foreach ($row->getContent() as $cell) {
        $thElement = $html->createElement("th");
        $thElement->setAttribute("colspan", $cell->getColspan());
        $thElement->setAttribute("rowspan", $cell->getRowspan());
        $tr->appendChild($thElement);
        foreach ($cell->getContent() as $parInCell) {
            self::paragraphWriting($html, $parInCell, $thElement);
        }
      }
   }
}
```

But in case of Smarty I have stuck with this:

```
{assign var="counter1" value=0}
{foreach from=$secCont->getContent() item=row}
    {if $row->getType() == "head"}

        {** capture group for adding inside thead*}
        {capture name="insideTableHead"}
            <tr>
                {foreach from=$row->getContent() item=cell}
                    <th colspan="{$cell->getColspan()}" rowspan="{$cell->getRowspan}">
                        {foreach from=$cell->getContent() item=parCont}
                            {include file="`$path_template`/paragraph.tpl"}
                        {/foreach}
                    </th>
                {/foreach}
            </tr>
        {/capture}

        {** we need thead only once if exists *}
        {assign var="counter1" value=$counter1+1}
        {if $counter1 == 1}
            <thead>
            {$smarty.capture.insideTableHead}
            </thead>
        {/if}
{/foreach}
```

The problem is that in capture group the code also is executed only once. Also Smarty version is 2, not 3.

Comment: I think you end your if condition for {if $row->getType() == "head"}. It might  help you for capture group.

Comment: That's only mechanical mistake while copying the code here. The problem is that this capture group is executed only once. And I want append it on each foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. The answer was so simple, how I missed it? 
Problem solved by placing first foreach loop inside `{capture}`:

```
{capture name="insideTableHead"}
    {foreach from=$secCont->getContent() item=row}
        {if $row->getType() == "head"}
            <tr>
                {foreach from=$row->getContent() item=cell}
                    <th colspan="{$cell->getColspan()}" rowspan="{$cell->getRowspan}">
                        {foreach from=$cell->getContent() item=parCont}
                            {include file="`$path_template`/paragraph.tpl"}
                        {/foreach}
                    </th>
                {/foreach}
            </tr>
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
{/capture}

{** we need thead only once if exists *}

<thead>
{$smarty.capture.insideTableHead}
</thead>
```